# Solr(Lucene) is indexing only the first document after adding a custom TokenFilter

Tags: search, lucene, solr, tokenize

I created a custom token filter which concatenates all the tokens in the stream. This is my `incrementToken()` function

```
public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {                        
    if (finished) {                                                         
        logger.debug("Finished");                                           
        return false;                                                       
    }                                                                       
    logger.debug("Starting");                                               
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();                             
    int length = 0;                                                         
    while (input.incrementToken()) {                                        
        if (0 == length) {                                                  
            buffer.append(termAtt);                                         
            length += termAtt.length();                                     
        } else {                                                            
            buffer.append(" ").append(termAtt);                             
            length += termAtt.length() + 1;                                 
        }                                                                   
    }                                                                       
    termAtt.setEmpty().append(buffer);                                      
    //offsetAtt.setOffset(0, length);                                       
    finished = true;                                                        
    return true;                                                            
}
```

I added the new Filter to the end of index and query analysis chain for a field and testing the filter from http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp seems to be working. The filter is concatenating the tokens in the stream. But on re-indexing the documents only my first document is getting indexed.

This is how my filter chain looks like.

```
        <analyzer type="index">                                             
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[-_]" replacement=" " />
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\s+]" replacement="" />
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />           
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />                  
            <filter class="solr.StopWordFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"               words="words.txt" />
            <filter class="org.custom.solr.analysis.ConcatFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>                                                         
        <analyzer type="query">                                             
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[-_]" replacement=" " />
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\s+]" replacement="" />
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />           
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />                  
            <filter class="solr.StopWordFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"               words="words.txt" />
            <filter class="org.custom.solr.analysis.ConcatFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
```

Without the `ConcatFilterFactory` all words are getting indexed properly but with `ConcatFilterFactory` only the first document is getting indexed.   What am I doing wrong? Kindly help me in understanding the problem.

**UPDATE :**

Finally figured out the issue.

```
if (finished) {                                                         
    logger.debug("Finished"); 
    finished = false;                                  
    return false;                                                       
}
```

Looks like the same class is being reused. Makes sense.

Comment: You should post your own answer and mark it as accepted. This question still shows up as one of the top unanswered questions for Lucene.

Comment: I worked on this years back and now I can't remember what exactly I did for the fix. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should write a unit test for your filter. It should fail even if your Analysis works. Apparently you forgot to add this line before returning false:

```
finished = false;
```